# What would I use to create a download service accessible from my AWS EC2 taking the files possibly from an AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am creating a website for my projects and I am creating a website to keep them and to allow people to download them from there.

How would I perform a download request from s3 from an EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following things.

1) Create a IAM user for the bucket in Amazon s3 where you have your files.

2) Create security policy according to your requirement and associate the policy with the IAM user.

3) Download the file into Amazon ec2 instance using s3 api calls, use the credentials of IAM user to access the bucket files.

Refer to the below link to use s3 bucket file:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

4) Send the file from Ec2 to your user for download.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [S3 static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html). Ideally, if your web page is simple enough (some HTML, CSS, JS and links to downloadable project material) then you may not need the complexity of web servers running on EC2.

If you genuinely need EC2, for example because you need server-side code, then pick the language/environment of your choice (JavaScript/Node.js, Python/Django, Java/Tomcat etc.) and then read the S3 SDK for the chosen language. It's pretty simple to download objects from S3 using the SDKs, or even the [command-line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).